# Need simple PDF viewer for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pdf

I am looking for a way to view PDFs within Eclipse (Juno).

I just need to quickly viewthe PDF, and do not need the capability to edit, search, or anything beyond viewing.

I have tried a few plugins, but they all switch to a new perspective when PDFs are opened.

Comment: Share some info about  plugins which you have tried? So will be helpful to all can suggest some other ideas on new plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try Pdf4Eclipse: http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse/ It was suggested next to the texlipse environment that already has its new perspective, so I think, this would not switch.

Comment: I have installed Pdf4Eclipse and it's exactly what I was looking for. It adds only a few buttons for changing the view to the toolbar. It displays PDFs very quickly.

Answer (score -2):

Try PDF viewer nice and simple, can be downloaded / installed from following eclipse marketplace website.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pdf-viewer#.Us-ZfvQeo0E

Comment: PDF viewer is no longer available; use pdf4eclipse instead.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pdf4eclipse